# How we can find the sum of all roots for $x^2+\cos x=2019$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How to find the sum of all real roots such that, $$x^2+\cos x=2019$$
Firstly I think to use numerical methods , but this shortcut is weak and depend on % error .As result, im searching for an algebraic way to solve such exercise. 
As result , is there any hint to crack this task ?

Comment: If $x$ is a root then $-x$ is also a root since your function is even.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily establish that $f(x)=x^2+\cos x -2019$ has a unique root in $[0,+\infty[$, lets say  $z>0$. Since $f$ is even, it will also have a unique root in $]-\infty, 0]$, which will be $-z$. Therefore, the sum of all roots is zero.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, you don't even have to look for the number of roots. Observe that $$x^2=(-x)^2\qquad \cos(x)=\cos(-x)$$ This implies that if $x_1$ is a root for your equation, so is $-x_1$. Therefore, you just have to evaluate $$\sum(x_1-x_1)=0$$